# Phone Number Validation (111) - 111- 1111 in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to create a sign up page in Android and I created a edittext to enter phone number. User can enter only number and I need the parenthesis and "-" to appear automatically.  will someone help me with the coding. Thank you!

```
     public class SignUpActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher {

EditText phoneNumber;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanseState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanseState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yahoo_signup_activity);
    phoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Mobile_number);
    phoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

   }
```

Comment: Have you even tried to do it yourself?  If so, what have you tried?

Comment: Which country phone number format are you focussing to implement? Number format vary from country to country, so appearance of parenthesis and hyphen would depend on it.

Comment: If the answer has helped you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an attribute `android:inputType="phone"` for an EditText (in XML or programatically) to make sure user can only enter phone numbers. Here is an [official explanation](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html#Type).